# Detect deprecated .Net classes and methods in my application?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a rather large application that targets .Net 4.5.2 and it's grown over the years.

While investigating an issue it was suggested that deprecated methods in the .Net library might be causing it.  Whether or not that's correct it then poses the question, how do I detect which calls I'm making are to deprecated methods?

I've checked that I'm compiling with warnings as errors and warning level 4 (maximum).

Comment: Warning level 4 as errors - that's severe. Should catch most things :-)

Comment: It should but it doesn't seem to detect deprecation.  If I add a call to something I know has been it carries on without complaint.

Comment: But won't catch libraries you use, that depend on deprecated methods.

Comment: Compiler Warning (level 2) CS0618 should catch it for methods you're calling directly though: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5ye6x1e.aspx

Comment: Besides obsolete methods, there can be other factors leading to such issues. You have to check Microsoft documentation on breaking changes carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is that yes an attribute marked as Obsolete will be triggered by CS0618.

It appears though that this isn't necessarily what Microsoft are doing with .Net classes and instead are simply indicating something is deprecated through the use of comments.

Look at [BlurBitmapEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.blurbitmapeffect(v=vs.110).aspx) as an example.  The online documentation shows it is Obsolete the comment in the metadata shows it as well but nobody has actually applied the Attribute to it.

Good luck finding anything else like that in a project without checking line by line.